# Equivalent condition for a proper ideal to be contained in the Jacobson radical.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let $\mathscr I$ denote the set of all proper ideals of $R$.
>   Let $J(R)$ denote the Jacobson Radical of $R$.
>   Show that if $I\in \mathscr I$ then $I\subseteq J(R)\iff I+J\neq R$ for any $J\in \mathscr I$.

Assume that   $I\subseteq J(R)$ and that $I+J= R$ for some $J\in \mathscr I$.
Then $J$ is contained in a maximal ideal say $M$ of $R$. Then $I+M=R$.

But I am unable to derive a contradiction from here. Please help.

Comment: In other words, $J(R)$ is the maximum superfluous ideal of a commutative ring with identity. It's the maximum superfluous right ideal in a noncommutative ring using the same reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $I+M=R$ you get a contradiction via $I\subseteq J(R)\subseteq M$
so that $I+M\subseteq M$.